# How to configure "https" in same domain for multiple ports?

Tags: debian, https, apache-virtualhost

I have a website(apache web server, ubuntu 14.04) setup http://example.com and configured with ports 1996 and 1980.

These links works with `http`

```
http://example.com/myproject
http://example.com:1996/
http://example.com:1980/
```

And then I installed SSL certs and configured this server to use `https`.

But these links doesn't work

```
https://example.com:1996 
https://example.com:1980
```

How to configure `https` in same domain for multiple ports?

default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
               ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ServerName example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/ssl_cert/signed_cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/ssl_cert/server.key

</VirtualHost>
```

ports.conf:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you see the ports up and running with a netstat -ntpl or ss -ntpl | cat ? If not Apache may not have even started properly and you need to check the logs for errors encountered.

Comment: Yes, the ports are up. Apache is also running and `http://example.com/myproject` still works. Issue is with `https` and specific ports 1996, 1980

Comment: If the ports are up then it means that you have configured apache to listen on those ports correctly. Check if the ServerName/ServerAlias is within that virtualhost block? Can you indicate how you are testing those links ? Are you testing locally on the machine or from another server/desktop ? Are there any errors appearing in the apache log files ?

Comment: @Nani, I just noticed that you haven't accepted an answer for any of the 4 still open questions you've asked. Accepting an answer is the best way to thank the person who took the time to answer you and, more importantly, shows the next user who finds your question that this answer worked for you. If the answers you have received did actually answer your question, please take a moment and [accept them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Debugging the user setup, it was found with `netstat` there is already a process using 1996/TCP:

```
netstat -nlp | grep 1996
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:1996 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 4729/python
```

So the configuration examples, were changed to 1997/TCP.

---

`Apache`/`mod_ssl` have to be told 1997/TCP and 1980/TCP are HTTPS ports. By default 443/TCP is already known, but any others TLS aware TCP ports have to be added to the configuration.

Otherwise, any non 443/TCP por, will be handled only as an HTTP capable port.

For instance, in CentOS, you have to add to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` and in Debian/Ubuntu at `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` the lines:

```
Listen 1997 https
Listen 1980 https
```

You also have to define the ports in the corresponding vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:1997>
Servername example.com
....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1980>
Servername example.com
....
</VirtualHost>
```

It is also little known, you can do something as (as an example only, do not use it if you still have the vhost using :*443):

```
<VirtualHost *:443 *:1980>
Servername example.com
....
</VirtualHost>
```

After editing the configuration files, you have to restart Apache. In Debian/Ubuntu, it is restarted doing:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

From [Apache - Binding to Addresses and Ports](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html)

> Specifying the protocol with Listen
>
> The optional second protocol argument of Listen is not required for
>   most configurations. If not specified, https is the default for port
>   443 and http the default for all other ports. The protocol is used to
>   determine which module should handle a request, and to apply protocol
>   specific optimizations with the AcceptFilter directive.
>
> You only need to set the protocol if you are running on non-standard
>   ports. For example, running an https site on port 8443:
>
> Listen 192.170.2.1:8443 https

**Important Note:** *there should only be configured one Listen line/directive per port. If you have already a Listen directive for these ports, you either comment them or add https on front of them. Otherwise, you will have a "Address already in use" when starting Apache*.

TLDR of last paragraph: you have already a duplicate Listen for at least 1996 in probably apache2.conf, take it out. (no, it is being used by another running service)

**Second Note:** Do not use ports you might have configured on other running services.

Comment: `(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:1996
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:1996
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.`

Comment: I get the above message, after restarting apache service with the changes that you suggested

Comment: I will add a note I deleted when editing the answer, because I thought you were showing your complete configuration (you arent)

Comment: If you are able to find the duplicate, do `cd /etc/apache2 ; grep -r 1996 *`

Comment: No, there are no duplicates

Comment: either a port duplicate, a vhost duplicate, or you are not restarting Apache and only starting it again. Unless you already have another service listening in port 1996?

Comment: `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 1996` for checking who is listening to what port. Also it should be `service apache2 restart`

Comment: `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 1996`                                                                                     `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1996            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4729/python`

Comment: A python process is already using 1996. Change it for something else. 1997? Run `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 1997` just in case.

Comment: And then do not forget to check the answer as correct. ;-P